# Flow Cannot assign function to because property abort is not writable

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I'm using Flow latest version (0.75.0) and I do not find the way to overwrite the `abort` method without Flow complains

```
interface Inter {
  abort(): void;
  done(): void;
}

class Hello implements Inter {
   abort() {}
   done(){}
}

let h = new Hello();

h.abort = function() {}
```

The error is the following.

```
../-:15: h.../ abort = function() {}
           ^ Cannot assign function to `h.abort` because property `abort` is not writable.
```

https://flow.org/try/#0JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJLmsg3gKGcgajgCMB7KMALmQDEBXEBMYUkAbj0IBNWJr7GzVhwC+OcQgA2cAM4zkACQiTJpZMAC2AB0kQNEcPPSQo2cfmQlyYABQBKbGIs8QEe1jFicusMgAWyAC8yK4A7orKqvYcOH4AdFYUQcgwDEwsIPaOQA

Comment: I think class methods are read only in Flow. Here's a GitHub issue regarding this: https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/6196

Comment: Thanks, there is a small workaround that solves the issue.

Answer (score 4):

As was pointed by Mark, wrapping the instance with `(h: any)` solves the issue. It's not perfect but avoid the error.

```
let h = new Hello();

(h: any).abort = function() {}
```